# In Spring Batch howto provide an Execution Context to a Job Launcher?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I would like to put some variable in an Execution Context - one of my steps need it - before launching the entire Job for test purpose (with mocking on DAO, readers, writers, cool stuff...).

Launching a single step with a given execution step is easy :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myjob")
protected  Job myjob;

// Enrich execution context
long myVariable = 42;
ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
context.putLong("response", myVariable);


// Initiate Launcher
JobLauncherTestUtils  jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(myjob);
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

// Launch Step (with context) : OK
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("oneStepBeyond",jobParameters,context);
```

But, on a job, howto deal with this ?
Any trick ?

```
// Launch entire job with context (1) ?
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobCachePlugged,   jobParameters /* no parameter for context */);

// Launch entire job with context (2) ?
JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution(new Long(1));
jobExecution.setExecutionContext(context);
// ... but no way to run/start directly a JobExecution... arfff...
```

Any idea

Thx a lot

Have a great day

Comment: How do they get set normally?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at StepExecutionListenerSupport ?
It gives you access to StepExecution from which you can access some scopes.

```
ExecutionContext stepContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
ExecutionContext jobContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
```